# Why is this segfaulting whilst building a binary tree?

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, binary-tree

I have found this line in this code through gdb to be seg faulting. However I can't seem to see why? It will run through 6/7 times before a seg fault occurs. Temp is a node in a linked list which contains a frequency (int), which I use to find the place in an ascending linked list to insert a new node.

```
while (ind == 0 && temp != NULL)
{
    temp = temp -> next;
    if (temp -> frequency > parent_node -> frequency) /*<--- SEG FAULT HERE */
    {
        parent_node -> next = temp -> next; /* parent points at higher freq node */ 
        temp -> next = parent_node; /* parent node is temp next */
        ind = 1;
    }
    if (temp -> next == NULL)
    {
        temp -> next = parent_node; 
        ind = 1;          
    }
}
```

Comment: `temp = temp -> next;` : `temp` become `NULL`

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your code is trying to do (although we know it's wrong). What are `temp` and `parent_node` pointing to on entry to the loop, and what do you want them to point to on exit from the loop? The two lines `parent_node->next = temp->next;` and `temp->next = parent_node;` seems to be creating a circular list with two nodes. Is that what you want?

Comment: In my head `parent_node->next = temp->next` (parent node is the one to be inserted), will point to temp -> next (a bigger value), and `temp->next = parent_node` will point the previous node at parent node, thus inserting parent node into the list

Comment: Note that the binary dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly indeed and should never have spaces around them in orthodox C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code which will insert a new node pointed to by `newnode` into a linked list where `liststart` points to the first node in the list or is `NULL` for an empty list:

```
if (liststart == NULL) {
    liststart = newnode;
    newnode->next = NULL;
} else {
    struct mylist *prev = liststart;

    while (prev->next != NULL && prev->next->frequency <= newnode->frequency) {
        prev = prev->next;
    }
    if (prev->next == NULL) {
        prev->next == newnode;
        newnode->next = NULL;
    } else {
        newnode->next = prev->next->next;
        prev->next = newnode;
    }
}
```

Here's an alternate version that uses pointers to pointers:

```
struct mylist **pprev;

pprev = &liststart;
while (*pprev != NULL && (*pprev)->frequency <= newnode->frequency) {
    pprev = &(*pprev)->next;
}
newnode->next = *pprev;
*pprev = newnode;
```

Answer (score 3):

You do `temp = temp->next` but `temp->next` might be `nullptr`. You must check its not null before trying to access it's memebers.

Comment: I thought I had done this as its all inside the `while ind == 0 && temp != NULL`

Comment: @Finlandia_C: That condition guards the dereference in line 3, but not the one right in the next line `if (temp -> frequency ...)` and beyond.

Comment: `temp != NULL` is one but you also need `temp->next != NULL` because you access members of  `temp->next`.

Comment: so... `if (temp != NULL && temp -> next != NULL && temp -> frequency > parent_node -> frequency)` ?

Comment: Something like this, yes. Generally, before doing a dereference (`foo->bar`) you must ensure somehow that `foo` is not NULL.

Comment: Or change your loop so it does it's business on the current node (which you know isn't null), then updates `temp = temp -> next` as the last instruction of the loop.

Comment: Can you show an example of how to do this? i like the idea but not sure how to implement

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you check that `temp` isn't null, then immediately update `temp`, so it may be null again.

(I don't like the name `temp` so I've changed it to `node` in my examples)

It's clearest if you decompose it, so:

```
while(ind == 0 && node != null) {
     node = node -> next;  // now node might be null
     doStuffWith(node);
}
```

Instead, you could move the assignment to the end of the loop. That means, of course, that the first time around, the assignment hasn't happened. So you may need to call it once outside the loop:

```
node = node -> next; // or some other initialisation of node
while(ind == 0 && node != null) {
     doStuffWith(node);
     node = node -> next;
}
```

Maybe you've been told about the DRY principle: "Don't repeat yourself", so you might feel uncomfortable about repeating `node = node -> next`. However it's an example of a very common pattern, for example:

```
int chars = stream.read(buffer);
while(chars != -1) {
     doSomethingWith(buffer);
     chars = stream.read(buffer);
}
```